# WIX installer- Duplicate primary key issue

Tags: installation, wix

I keep getting errors like this in my Product.wxs file.

The primary key 'ExitDialog/Finish/EndDialog/Return/1' is duplicated in table 'ControlEvent'

There is no such duplicate entry that I have made manually to the config file. How do I find out where this is getting duplicated? Just commenting the affected line shows a duplicate in the next entry.

The primary key 'WixUI_Mode' is duplicated in table 'Property'.

I can't go on commenting all the lines. Is there some tool or some other way to find out which other entry could be causing this duplicate? Some other instruction in the product.wxs file that I have authored could have implicitly added that key to the property table. I need to find out the offending line and take it out. Looking at product.wxs file entries it is not evident which one that line could be. How do I find that out?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending over a week struggling with WiX. I have decided that Installsheild is the best way to go. If you have an experienced hand at WiX then by all means go ahead and use it. If not, then your best bet would be to use a paid tool. The amount of hours your billing while learning WiX makes WiX far more expensive than an installsheild license!

Just my two cents!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you included some fragments in your project that contain the same base controls as your default dialogs.

Please make sure that your project doesn't include other project files.

Comment: My wix setup project is added to the main solution that has all the other solution's projects. Are you saying that's not the way to do it?

Comment: The way you added your setup project is correct. I was referring to what you added in the actual project (its content).

Comment: My Wix project has nothing else other than a Product.wxs file

Answer (score 0):

Can be caused if you have the same 'Id' for multiple items